# Ggenerating UUID in Jruby using java.util.UUID?

Tags: jruby, uuid

Is there any Gem available to generate UUID in Jruby using java.util.UUID?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a gem, but this is trivial code in JRuby:

```
$ jirb
irb(main):001:0> uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID
=> #<Java::JavaUtil::UUID:0x37a6af53>
irb(main):002:0> puts uuid
944b0019-d122-4f2b-9e85-23836e0f3d72
```